# how to create 20 objects each time in loop when holding a json object representing 500 objects?

Tags: android, loops, memory

I have fetched an array of 500 ints from a HTTP request using Volley library.

Each and every one of the 500 ints at the array will be used to create a separate HTTP request itself. The issue is that the memory can't hold 500 objects while iterating through the array length and crash due to outOfMemoryException.

Here is my code:

```
private void networkRequest() {
        httpRequest = new HttpRequest(this, Global.TOP_STORIES, new HttpRequest.OnHttpCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(String response) {
                createNewsList(response);

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String error) {
                Log.i("error", error);
            }
        });
        httpRequest.request();
    }

    private void createNewsList(String response) {
        final Gson gson = new Gson();
        int[] topStories = gson.fromJson(response, int[].class);
        //TODO - fix the loop to iterate through all topStories length
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            String url = Global.BASE_NEWS_URL + topStories[i] + Global.NEWS_ENDPOINT;
            Log.i("url", url);

            httpRequest = new HttpRequest(this, url, new HttpRequest.OnHttpCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(String response) {
                    NewsItem newsItem = gson.fromJson(response, NewsItem.class);
                    if (newsItem != null) {
                        newsItemList.add(newsItem);
                        Log.i("item", newsItem.toString());
                        newsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    Log.i("number of news items", "number of newsItems " + newsItemList.size());
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String error) {
                    Log.i("create list error", error);
                }
            });
            httpRequest.request();
        }
    }
```

As you can see, right now I am only limiting the loop to iterate only 20 times so I can verify that it actually works and it does.

How would an implementation of an SQLite injection of 20 objects each time in loop look like, according to my needs?

Also, here is my HttpRequest class if it has anything to do with it:

```
public class HttpRequest {

    private Context context;
    private String url;
    private OnHttpCompleteListener onHttpCompleteListener;
    private RequestQueue queue;

    public HttpRequest(Context context, String url, OnHttpCompleteListener onHttpCompleteListener) {
        this.context = context;
        this.url = url;
        this.onHttpCompleteListener = onHttpCompleteListener;
        queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    }

    public void request(){
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if (response != null){
                    onHttpCompleteListener.onComplete(response);
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                onHttpCompleteListener.onError(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    public interface OnHttpCompleteListener{
        void onComplete(String response);
        void onError(String error);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to use pagination while calling JSON from API

Comment: Try to use ThreadPoolExecutor while hitting an HTTP request.

Comment: **Multi-threading** would be the case for you but also find out the way of reusing existing object instead of creating new one in iterations.

Comment: @JeelVankhede can you please reference me for a specific example that would fit my needs?